# Unable to Access New Linux Samba Share from Windows 10

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I can't connect to the Linux Samba share just created from Windows 10.
I get the "You do not have permission to access..." error message on Windows.
Any help will be appreciated.  It looks like I am sooo close!  FYI, I can ping, ssh into the linux box, etc.  Network connectivity doesn't appear to be an issue.

Here's the smb.conf...

```
    [global]
        workgroup = SAMBA
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        log level = 2
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        hosts allow = 192.168.1.220 192.158.1.230 192.168.1.240 192.168.1.0/24

[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        valid users = %S, %D%w%S
        browseable = No
        read only = No
        inherit acls = Yes

    [printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/tmp
        printable = Yes
        create mask = 0600
        browseable = No

[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/drivers
        write list = @printadmin root
        force group = @printadmin
        create mask = 0664
        directory mask = 0775

    [fshare]
        browseable = yes
        path = /home/fshare
        public = yes
        writeable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
        guest only = yes
        create mode = 0777
        directory mode = 0777
        valid users = sambauser
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to chmod the share folder. As root :

chmod -R 777 /home/shares/

Quite brutal, but enough for my home needs.